# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_dir'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def _get_file_writer(self):
        """Returns the default FileWriter instance. Recreates it if closed."""
        if not self._write_to_disk:
            self.file_writer = DummyFileWriter(logdir=self.logdir)
            self.all_writers = {self.file_writer.get_logdir(): self.file_writer}
            return self.file_writer

        if self.all_writers is None or self.file_writer is None:
            if 'purge_step' in self.kwargs.keys():
                most_recent_step = self.kwargs.pop('purge_step')
                self.file_writer = FileWriter(logdir=self.logdir, **self.kwargs)
                self.file_writer.add_event(
                    Event(step=most_recent_step, file_version='brain.Event:2'))
                self.file_writer.add_event(
                    Event(step=most_recent_step, session_log=SessionLog(status=SessionLog.START)))
            else:
                self.file_writer = FileWriter(logdir=self.logdir, **self.kwargs)
            self.all_writers = {self.file_writer.get_logdir(): self.file_writer}
        return self.file_writer

    def add_scalar(self, tag, scalar_value, global_step=None, walltime=None):
        """Add scalar data to summary.
```

> ```
>   File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\tensorboardX\writer.py", line 310, in _get_file_writer
>     self.file_writer = FileWriter(logdir=self.logdir, **self.kwargs)
> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_dir'
> ```

Comment: Exactly what the error says. You are passing the parameter `log_dir` to the `__init__` function of the `FileWriter` class, which it isn't expecting. Evidently it is contained in `self.kwargs`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is outside this snippet of code, probably in the initialisation of whatever class `_get_file_writer` is part of. Your dict `self.kwargs` contains a `log_dir` key that you're passing to FileWriter through `**self.kwargs` whereas [tf.summary.FileWriter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter) expects `logdir`.